# \widehat in \index inside align environment does not show up properly in the index

Tags: indexing, makeindex

Why does the `\widehat` mathematical symbol show up as follows in the MWE below? [image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\xv}{\operatorname{xv}}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]

\newcommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{\textbf{\sffamily Symbols}}
\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
  \par\textbf{\sffamily#1}\par
  \nopagebreak
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  E=mc^2\index{. xv@$\widehat{\xv}_n$}
\end{align*}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect\widehat` The contents of `\index` are written to an external file which always triggers full expansion and `\widehat` is not protected.

Comment: That solved the problem, Henri, thanks. Do you want to provide it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `.idx` file, you will find

```
\indexentry{. xv@$\mathaccent "0362\relax {\xv  }_n$}{1}
```

which fails because `"` is a quoting character in `.idx` files, so this is interpreted as if it were `\mathaccent 362` changing hexadecimal into decimal.

A way out could be `\protect\widehat`, but I'd not recommend this. The problem is that

```
\widehat{\xv}
```

does not behave as an operator as far as spacing is concerned, because it ends up being an Acc atom, which is later treated as an ordinary one. Try with

```
\begin{align*}
  \xv A &= 2 \\
  \hxv A &= 2 \\
  \widehat{\xv} A &= 2
\end{align*}
```

where `\xv` and `\hxv` are properly defined by

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\xv}{xv}
\DeclareMathOperator{\hxv}{\widehat{\xv}}
```

The output is

[image]

and you can immediately see the problem.

Using `\hxv` in the `\index` command will write `\hxv` (and similarly `\xv` will write itself) instead of doing nasty expansions. The proposed definition of `\xv` is to be preferred to `\newcommand{\xv}{\operatorname{xv}}` also for this reason.

Beware that the same problem with `"` will appear with delimiters: protect also things such as `\lbrace`.